# Function inside a model in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am working in Accounts and i have to add expense. So for that i used the following code inside model

```
public function accounts_entry($type,$ledger_type,$amount,$against,$remarks,$entity_name,$posting_date,
                                  $ref_no,$ref_date,$payment_method,$fiscal_year)
    {
            $this->account              =   $ledger_type;
            $this->debit                =   $amount;
            $this->credit               =   0;
            $this->against              =   $against;
            $this->remarks              =   $remarks;
            $this->entity_name          =   $entity_name;

            ....

            $this->save();
    }
```

For each entry of expense i have to do two entries into table tabGLEntry(with value in debit and credit fields interchanged). If i try the same code once more then the last value will be saved. How can i save the model two times. I don't wanna use `$model= new Tableglentry ();`
In Yii1 i could have used
           `$this->unsetAttributes();` after   `$this->save();` that way i could have saved both entries. Is there any such way in Yii2? (unsetAttributes is not there in Yii2)

Edit:-
i don't want to use new model object. so i tried like this

```
$this->isNewRecord = true;
            if($this->save())
            {
                $this->setAttributes(['id'=>NULL,'account'=>NULL,'debit' => NULL,'credit'=>NULL,'against' => NULL,
                'remarks'=>NULL,'entity_name' => NULL,'posting_date'=>NULL,'reference_no' => NULL,'reference_date'=>NULL,
                'payment_method_id' => NULL,'voucher_category'=>NULL,'fiscal_year' => NULL,'voucher_no'=>NULL,'name' => NULL,]);
            }
```

so i thought it will solve my problem but it didn't. I got an error like this

```
Integrity constraint violation
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `tabGLEntry` (`payment_method_id`, `reference_no`, `reference_date`, `posting_date`, `remarks`, `fiscal_year`, `account`, `debit`, `credit`, `against`, `entity_name`, `voucher_category`, `voucher_no`, `name`, `id`) VALUES (1, '', NULL, '2015-10-28', '3', '2015-2016', 'Cash', '3', '0', 'Sales', 'general', 0, 'IV-1516-16', 'GL69', 8)
```

only my first entry is getting saved other one is not because both are getting same id value(Primary key)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new Model obj.
[See here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4596) the function was removed because no default values from the DB are set on creation.

You can use setAttributes to null as it also mentioned in the issue linked above, or write your own clear method if required.

Just use

```
$this->setIsNewRecord(true);

$values= [
  'account'=>NULL,
  'debit' => NULL,
  'credit'=>NULL,
  'against' => NULL,
  'remarks'=>NULL,
  'entity_name' => NULL,
  'posting_date'=>NULL,
  'reference_no' => NULL,
  'reference_date'=>NULL,
  'payment_method_id' => NULL,
  'voucher_category'=>NULL,
  'fiscal_year' => NULL,
  'voucher_no'=>NULL,
  'name' => NULL,
];
//or create a simpler null value array of all safe Attributes with:
$values = array_fill_keys($model->safeAttributes(), null);

// set this values of your safeattributes to null or your new values.
$this->setAttributes($values, $safeOnly = true);

// set the values of your keys (here `id`) to null
$this->setAttribute(['id' => null ], $safeOnly = false);
```

Then you should be able to save with your same model again.

Comment: i guess it didn't work because you only set the safe attributes. the id and the scenario are also have to be changed/cleared. Otherwise the model will think it was already inserted to the db.

Comment: well i did set id to null. i didn't work as well. there is no sceanrio defined. do i have to set all attributes to null even if they are not being used?

Comment: i guess you have to set isNewRecord to true after each save. I think you have to set all attributes to null which you have set (also those setted by behaviors).

Comment: how is your primary key defined? from your code above you didn't set the `id` to null. You also have to use the function `setIsNewRecord($value)` to change the record back to its new state because it sets the _oldAttributes in the ActiveRecord.

Comment: i have used $this->isNewRecord = true; isn't that enough? i have also set id to null

Comment: as i written above use the function `->setIsNewRecord(true)` just to be sure. It seems that the primary key isn't changed with setAttribute because it's not a `safe attribute` so you have to change it manually or change the parameter `setAttribute($values, $safeOnly = false )`